# Split list of equal length in multiple columns of pandas dataframe into individual row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multiple-columns, series

suppose I have a DataFrame
[image: Here is the dataframe I have]
I want to convert this into dataframe which has single value in each row like below
[image: Dataframe that is needed]
Is there any way to obtain this?

Comment: `df.explode(list('CD'))`

Comment: Use `explode` on the needed columns